# _world->DestroyBody(bodyB); does not destroy body in cocos2d in iphone

Tags: ios4, cocos2d-iphone, fixtures

This is the code :

```
for(NSValue *fixtureValue in fixtures)
{
    b2Fixture *fixture;
    fixture = (b2Fixture*)[fixtureValue pointerValue];

        if(contact.fixtureA==fixture && contact.fixtureB == carFixture)
   {
      NSLog(@"Car hit outersquare!");
      [redcar stopAction:moveAction];
      _world->DestroyBody(bodyB);   // does not destroy body 
      [self createCarBody];
      speed = 0;
      break;
    }
 }

please help...
```

Comment: I read that when you check a body while it colliding it can't be destroyed. But, you can add it to array and destroy after the bodies has collided.

Comment: @gixdev : I need to do following things for car game :
I have one car sprite which will be moving in circular track. m applying "CCMoveBy” on car & if car collides with track, then I want to stop the car & then destroy the body of car.

so, will you give some code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is 'bodyB' coming from? You mean

```
_world->DestroyBody(carFixture->GetBody());
```

or something like that?

Anyway, I recommend you to use CCBox2D for using Box2D with cocos2d for iphone.

- [CCBox2D](https://github.com/axcho/CCBox2D)
- [[CCBox2D] I made a cocos2d-flavored wrapper for Box2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/15175)